# Imputation method for missing values that are irrelevant

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, surrogate

I have a data set $\mathbf X$, with around 20 predictors, which is a matrix of parameters of a surrogate model. For each observation $\mathbf i$ of $\mathbf X$, the surrogate model was trained to predict a different simulated response vector $\mathbf y_{sim,i}$ and its parameters were recorded. In every observation, there are several missing values/parameters. For a given observation $\mathbf i$, a predictor with a missing value was deemed irrelevant in predicting $\mathbf y_{sim,i}$ since the sampled values of the predictor were uncorrelated with $\mathbf y_{sim,i}$.

I would like to now regress the matrix $\mathbf X$ of parameters on to a single *true* response vector $\mathbf y_{true}$ and estimate coefficients. However, since $\mathbf X$ has too many missing values, a simple fit is not possible.

My objective is to find an imputation method that can essentially "ignore" the missing values, so that when $\mathbf X$ is fitted to $\mathbf y_{true}$, the estimated coefficients are as close as possible to those that would be estimated via gradient descent (GD). To elaborate, GD would find the coefficients that minimize the sum over all observations of the squared error between the $\mathbf i$th value of the $\mathbf y_{true}$ vector and the surrogate model at observation $\mathbf i$ (where only the relevant predictors are included).

I have successfully implemented GD for a linear model; however, for any non-linear model, it is far too slow. Thus, I would like to impute the missing values to create a new data set, which would then allow me to estimate the coefficients with a single fit.

The multiple-imputation methods that are known to me are the following:

- Zero,
- Mean,
- Regression,
- K-nearest neighbors (KNN),
- Fuzzy K-means (FKM),
- Singular value decomposition (SVD),
- Bayesian principal component analysis (bPCA), and
- Multiple imputations by chained equations (MICE).

However, in the comparison studies that I have read, data is assumed to be missing at random (MAR), and I do not know whether MAR is equivalent to the nature of my missing data.

Comment: How can you have correlation for a given observation?  Correlation is something that happens across observations, not for one observation.

Comment: Very good point. Let me elaborate: the data set represents the parameters of a surrogate model trained on simulated data. For a given observation in the data set, a predictor's value is the coefficient of a regression across multiple *simulated* observations of a *simulated* response. Therefore, the relevant predictors are "correlated" with the simulated observations. I am going to find a way to rephrase the question to say that the predictors are simply "present" at a given observation and are "relevant" for the *true* response, or something along those lines.

Comment: @jbowman. Does my updated question make more sense now?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Thanks!